# Tirar um elemento que está dentro de um iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe

Eu precisava tirar um título que está dentro de uma iframe, eu fiz isso com jquery mas demora muito pra sumir ou até mesmo nem some. Eu fiz assim com jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("iframe").contents().find(".titulo").css("display","none");
});
```

Eu já tentei assim também, fora do $(document).ready():

```
$("iframe").contents().find(".titulo").css("display","none");
```

Mas não adiantou, eu acho que se for com css ele some logo que a página for carregada, teria como fazer com css?
Se não, como eu poderia fazer com jquery que logo que entrasse na página esse título não fosse visível? 
Me ajudem por favor,

Comment: mas `$(document).ready` se refere quando a página estiver pronta e não o `iframe` dentro dela. Tente assim `$('iframe').ready`

Comment: Tenta assim: `$('iframe').on("load", function(){
   $("iframe").contents().find(".titulo").remove();
});
`

Comment: Obrigado, o do sam funcionou :) Eu fiquei mil anos pra tenta arruma isso ai

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não conheço uma forma de detectar o carregamento do DOM dentro de um iframe, mas usando `.on()` você consegue disparar o evento `"load"` quando o iframe tiver sido completamente carregado, e assim remover o elemento desejado:

```
$('iframe').on("load", function(){
   $("iframe")
   .contents()
   .find(".titulo")
   .remove();
});
```